# Check if the second monitor is connected in .NET (dual monitor setup, laptop with the docking station)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multiple-monitors

Here is the problem:

I have an application (**C#.NET, Windows 7**) that remembers the location of the main form on exit. On load the settings are retrieved and applied. I have a problem with the users that run dual monitors setup.

We mostly use HP laptops with docking stations and secondary monitors. Users sometimes have to undock their laptops. When the user has an application running on a secondary monitor, then shuts it down, undocks the laptop and restarts the application - it is off bounds (since the location is remembered by application).

I need a way to see if the second monitor is connected.

---

Here is what I have already tried:

System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens - this array has two monitors even if the laptop is undocked (I assume its due to the fact that the second monitor still shows up in Control Panel -> Display)

System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MonitorCount - the same applies to this property.

Thank you.

---

Thank you guys, but the problem with our laptops in this case was the following:

We are using 2x client software on our laptops to access the applications that run on the server. 2x itself has a setting Disable Desktop Composition in Compatibility tab. If this is checked off the second monitor always appears to be available (even when the laptop is undocked).

So the fix was to turn this setting on.

Thanks again

Comment: I've [answered this question in detail here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681738/how-do-i-determine-if-a-window-is-off-screen/4681861#4681861), but considering that your laptops *think* they have an additional monitor connected even when they do not, I'm not sure if it will work. The linked answer either has the solution, or this problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Thanks Cody, but that does not fix this problem. Like you mentioned my laptops still "think" they have two monitors after being undocked from the station. I thought there might be a property that would check for the "active" monitors, but i guess tough luck.

Comment: How exactly does the second monitor "show up" in Control Panel -> Display? Does Windows actually think that it's using it?

Comment: I see two active monitors in Control Panel -> Display. Sorry I can't post pictures yet as I am a new user. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...  It may not help if things are as bad as you are describing (seeing the monitor in Control Panel and all), but it's worth a shot.  Add the following method to your project:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Returns whether at least the titlebar of a form would be on a viewable portion of the screen
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="FormLocation">The location of the form</param>
  /// <param name="FormSize">The size of the form</param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  protected bool FormWouldBeVisible(Point FormLocation, Size FormSize)
  {
     //The FromPoint method returns the screen OR CLOSEST SCREEN to the point you give...
     Screen theScreen = Screen.FromPoint(FormLocation);
     int titleBar = SystemInformation.CaptionHeight;
     //Test if enough of the title bar will be visible so that the user can move the form if desired...
     if ((theScreen.Bounds.Bottom >= (FormLocation.Y + titleBar)) && //If the bottom of the screen is below the title bar
           (theScreen.Bounds.Top <= FormLocation.Y) && //If the top of the screen is above the top of the title bar
           (theScreen.Bounds.Left <= (FormLocation.X + FormSize.Width - titleBar)) && //If the left of the screen is left of a little bit of the title bar
           (theScreen.Bounds.Right >= (FormLocation.X + titleBar))) //If the right of the screen is right of a little bit of the title bar
     {
        //The form is moveable
        return true;
     }
     //The point at which the form is to be loaded is not on a visible part of any screen
     else return false;
  }
```

Then when you load the location of your form, pass the point to which you intend to load it and the size of your form.  The method will return true if the form will be visible enough that the user could move it, and false otherwise.  If it's false, just put it on the main screen.  I use this for my program using a laptop on a docking station with flawless results -- but again if your PC's are somehow reporting extra monitors when they don't exist, I don't know what the results will be.  If that's really true, I suspect it's a problem with the docking station (or Windows...), and you might not have a good way around this through code.